# How to change range protection based upon value?

Tags: google-apps-script

I share spreadsheet to coleagues with two sheets "My actual projects", "New projects" and I would like to lock these sheets by opening (more or less works), but I need to keep cell A3 free for changes, in A3 is roll down menu, if user select one item from list it will open next three cells, if user delete value from A3 cell it lock 3 cells again back. Below is code, I am really crazy (spent 5 hours). I see that locked ranges changed like owner, but others do not see any change. Can you please help me. Thx

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var myActualProjectsSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var myActualProjectsProtection = myActualProjectsSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);

  for (var j = 0, jLen = myActualProjectsProtection.length; j < jLen; j++) {
    myActualProjectsProtection[j].remove();
  }

  var newProjectsSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('New projects');
  var newProjectsProtection = newProjectsSheet.protect();
  var newProjectsUnprotected = newProjectsSheet.getRange('A3');
  newProjectsProtection.setUnprotectedRanges([newProjectsUnprotected]);
  newProjectsProtection.removeEditors(newProjectsProtection.getEditors());

  var myActualProjectsSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('My actual projects');
  var myActualProjectsProtection = myActualProjectsSheet.protect();
  var myActualProjectsUnprotected = myActualProjectsSheet.getRange('A3');
  myActualProjectsProtection.setUnprotectedRanges([myActualProjectsUnprotected]);
  myActualProjectsProtection.removeEditors(myActualProjectsProtection.getEditors());

}

function onEdit(e){

  var myActualProjectsSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var Protection = myActualProjectsSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
  var myActualProjectsUnprotected1 = myActualProjectsSheet.getRange('A3');
  var myActualProjectsUnprotected2 = myActualProjectsSheet.getRange('A17');
  var myActualProjectsUnprotected3 = myActualProjectsSheet.getRange('A19');
  var myActualProjectsUnprotected4 = myActualProjectsSheet.getRange('A21');

  for (var j = 0, jLen = Protection.length; j < jLen; j++) {
    Protection[j].remove();
  }

    var myActualProjectsProtection = myActualProjectsSheet.protect();

  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('My actual projects').getRange('A3').getValue() != ''){
    myActualProjectsProtection.setUnprotectedRanges([myActualProjectsUnprotected1,myActualProjectsUnprotected2,myActualProjectsUnprotected3,myActualProjectsUnprotected4]);
  }
  else{
    myActualProjectsProtection.setUnprotectedRanges([myActualProjectsUnprotected1]);
  }
  myActualProjectsProtection.removeEditors(myActualProjectsProtection.getEditors());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's not possible to achieve because of the way Protected Ranges work in Sheets.

Protecting acts on each Range object, so unless you protect each cell one by one, you can't "unprotect" them individually as the Protect is a property of the Range you defined. Adding a new protection with editors for a certain cell doesn't work either, since the most restrictive protection rule (the first) has more priority.

Also, this is a bad idea. As you can read in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

> If you don’t want people to change the content in a spreadsheet, you can protect it. **This shouldn’t be used as a security measure**. People can print, copy, paste, and import and export copies of a protected spreadsheet. Only share spreadsheets with people you trust.

Adding protected ranges in an onEdit or onOpen function is not ok either. The Protected Ranges don't rewrite themselves, it will create a new layer for each edit or open trigger running. It will end up being very confusing and not working as expected.

Comment: Thak you, I put this into drawer for time being, it helps me to freeze some problem and after some time to try it again